# Apply object-fit to an element with Typescript in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, object-fit

Im trying to use object-fit for an element in my app. My IDE doesnt recognize this:

> child.style.objectFit = 'cover';

For some reason. It has squigly lines under objectFit. And when i do this:

> child.style.setProperty( 'object-fit', 'cover', '!important' );

It wont show up in the Inspector of my browser. So it doesnt apply the code.

Why does it behaves so strangely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently your IDE (and environment) can't recognize the typings properly. To overcome that you can try casting it before using:

```
(child.style as any).objectFit = 'cover';
```

Comment: this works, i can now see it in my inspector. my video doesn't scale to its parent div though . but that's another topic. thanks!